# Why add to home screen is not available for non-PWA?

Tags: performance, web, browser, electron, progressive-web-apps

Is there any performance issue in providing A2HS for non-PWA? If not, why web browsers don't give A2HS for non-PWA? I am asking because I have an idea to make an electron based app to provide A2HS for websites. What do you guys think about it?

Comment: A2HS in chrome is only available to PWAs that meet all of the criteria for a PWA. You can add a shortcut for a plain website to a home screen. But that would not be installed like a PWA.

Comment: But I don't see any A2HS button on my chrome(Linux).

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.